# J2ME web service response parsing

Tags: xml, soap, java-me

I use Netbeans to generate stubs for SOAP web service.

How can I parse the web response which is in xml or html for rss feeds? any links in parsing SOAP response or html response would be great.

Comment: you can use SAX Parser or Rest Parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target devices support SAX from JSR 172, you should go with this parser. It will reduce your app's final jar size (no libs imported). There is a good sample at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/JSR_172:_XML_Parsing_Example It actually unmarshalls the XML into Java objects.

After you feel confident you may try my generic approach to unmarshalling in Java ME at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/xml-data-binding.html

Comment: Let me try it out and get back to you